# Changing the format from #### to numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I am typing numbers into cells, instead of numbers appearing it shows `#####`. I click on accounting or numbers and it doesn't make the change. How can I change it and or why does this happen?

Answer (score 3):

#### When I am typing numbers into cells, instead of numbers it shows `#####`

This is because the cell is not wide enough to display the number.

> If you're looking at an Excel spreadsheet and instead of seeing
>   numbers you're only seeing `######`, it usually means the number is
>   wider than the column.
>
> All you need to do is increase the column width in order to see the
>   number instead.
>
> 1. Position your mouse pointer on the right boundary of a column heading until it turns into a double-sided arrow.
> 2. Drag the boundary until the column is the width that you want, and the number in the cell displays correctly.

Source [Excel Tip: If You See #### Instead of Numbers](http://ides.winnefox.org/node/240)